# How can I inherit from std::future in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a new Future class inherited from std::future and has some more members and methods. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Future<T>: public std::future<T>{

private: 
mem1;
public:
void function1();
...
}
```

I am stuck at constructing the class. Initially, the code would return std:: future itself, wherein the object would be created as

```
std::future<void> fut;
fut=promise.get_future();
```

Want I want to do now is:

```
Future<void> fut;
fut=promise.get_future();
```

This does not work.

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Future<void>’ and ‘std::future<void>’)   
fut=(promise.get_future());
                         ^
```

How can I assign the promise.get_future() to my new derived class?

Edit: I understand that inheriting from std classes is generally a no-no, but I would really appreciate if someone could tell how I could do this using inheritance. I see that I can create a std::future member inside the Future class and overload its methods, but I want to know how to do this using inheritance.

Edit2: Why I want inheritance-
The existing functionality has std::future as return type. I want to add one public method to std::future which will use just one private member. Hence I felt that inheriting from std::future would be a good option as there is very little that I have to add to it instead of creating a new class with std::future member and writing overloading methods.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is `composition > inheritance`.

Comment: Can you overload the assignment operator?

Comment: @AlanBirtles _"Deriving from std classes is generally undefined behaviour"_ — Could you explain why? Does the Standard forbid this? I am not aware of any such restriction. (Yes, treating such classes in a polymorphic way could result in UB, but inheritance does not equal polymorphism.) Moreover, deriving from many `std` classes is recommended (such as deriving from `std::true_type`).

Comment: Prefer free functions over member functions if possible. Avoid inheriting from value classes with no virtual members, it is generally a poor design.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with normal inheritance. You need to write a constructor that accepts a `std::future`. You cannot by default construct Derived from Base. You got to write a custom implementation.

In general, you shouldn't inherit from `std::future` or STL classes. What if you accidentally have member/function with the same name as one of `std::future` private members/functions? All of them are implementation defined.

Just put the `std::future` as a member.

Comment: "What if you accidentally have member/function with the same name as one of std::future private members/functions?" ... yes what then? I don't see the problem with that

Comment: @ALX23z I want to add 1 private member and one public method to std::future. Hence I thought I'd just inherit from std::future instead of creating a new class with std::future member.